# What does the tuples we mention inside openpyxl.reference method mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What does the tuples we mention inside `openpyxl.reference` method mean? in following :-

```
from openpyxl.chart import (
Reference,
Series,
BarChart
)

wb = load_workbook('revenue.xlsx')
wsheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sales')
print (wsheet)


data =   Reference(wsheet, min_col=5, min_row=2, max_col=5, max_row=10)
```

OR

```
data =   Reference(wsheet, (5, 2), (5, 10))
```

I went through some docs but they were not that clear to me

Comment: did the below explanation help? feel free to accept the answer (tick on left) or add comments.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for [`openpyxl.chart.reference`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/_modules/openpyxl/chart/reference.html#Reference) is relatively short. An excerpt is below. Also see [Creating a chart](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/charts/introduction.html#creating-a-chart) in OpenPyXL documentation. The parameters `(5, 2)` and `(5, 10)` refer to start and end points of the range of cells in the Excel worksheet containing the data for the chart you are plotting.

```
class Reference(Strict):

    """
    Normalise cell range references
    """

    min_row = MinMax(min=1, max=1000000, expected_type=int)
    max_row = MinMax(min=1, max=1000000, expected_type=int)
    min_col = MinMax(min=1, max=16384, expected_type=int)
    max_col = MinMax(min=1, max=16384, expected_type=int)
    range_string = String(allow_none=True)

    def __init__(self,
                 worksheet=None,
                 min_col=None,
                 min_row=None,
                 max_col=None,
                 max_row=None,
                 range_string=None
                 ):
        if range_string is not None:
            sheetname, boundaries = range_to_tuple(range_string)
            min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = boundaries
            worksheet = DummyWorksheet(sheetname)
```